# wxPython undesirable space on bottom of grid widget and inside grid border

Tags: python, gridview, grid, wxpython

Python 3.8 x64 | Windows 10 x64 | wxPython version 4.1.0

Been searching everywhere for an answer on this to no avail. I created a simple `wx.grid.Grid()` widget and added a border around the grid. The issue is there's dead space included between the grid widget and it's border towards the bottom of the grid. I am not describing the space around the outside of the border which is added using sizers. The border I chose is `wx.BORDER_THEME` and I don't want to change this since the rest of my GUI utilizes this same border. I do have the row size set to 20, but the issue persists no matter what the size of the row is changed to.

I've included a minimal, reproducible code example below. It looks like a lot at first glance, but it really isn't and is very basic.

Also attached is a picture illustrating what I attempted to describe above. The bottom line in the attached photo is the border and the upper line is the grid.

**Minimal Code Example:**

```
import wx
import wx.grid


class MyGrid(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='Grid With Undesirable Space', size=(650, 300))
        self.SetMinSize(self.GetSize())  # set min size of frame
        self.rows, self.columns = 1, 4

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.grid = wx.grid.Grid(panel, style=wx.BORDER_THEME)
        self.grid.CreateGrid(self.rows, self.columns)
        self.grid.ShowScrollbars(wx.SHOW_SB_NEVER, wx.SHOW_SB_NEVER)  # remove scroll bars

        # set all cells in first row Read Only
        attr = wx.grid.GridCellAttr()
        attr.SetReadOnly(True)
        self.grid.SetRowAttr(0, attr)

        self.grid.HideRowLabels()
        self.grid.SetRowSize(0, 20)
        self.grid.DisableDragRowSize()

        self.grid.SetColLabelSize(20)

        self.grid.SetColLabelValue(0, 'Nintendo')
        self.grid.SetColLabelValue(1, 'Super Nintendo')
        self.grid.SetColLabelValue(2, 'Nintendo 64')
        self.grid.SetColLabelValue(3, 'Nintendo GameCube')

        v_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        v_box.Add(self.grid, proportion=0, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, border=10)
        panel.SetSizer(v_box)
        self.Layout()

        # set the initial size of columns based on initial frame size
        self.resize_with_frame()

        self.grid.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, lambda event: self.resize_with_frame())

    def resize_with_frame(self):
        """Dynamically resize columns with the size of the frame."""
        width, height = self.GetClientSize()
        for column in range(self.columns):
            self.grid.SetColSize(column, (width - 20) / self.columns)  # width - 20 for border of 10 on both sides
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    gui = MyGrid()
    gui.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, you are passing control over to the system, so it makes the decision about the border. Using `wx.BORDER_DEFAULT` or `wx.BORDER_NONE` should get rid of it. The notes are clear `In general, specifying wxBORDER_THEME will cause a border of some kind to be used, chosen by the platform and control class. To leave the border decision entirely to wxWidgets, pass wxBORDER_DEFAULT.`

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, not sure what you're talking about for a couple of reasons. Firstly, I am not taking control over the system, on Windows `wx.BORDER_THEME` is the same as `wx.BORDER_DEFAULT`, I just wanted to be explicit so I chose `wx.BORDER_THEME`. You can try it yourself using `wx.BORDER_DEFAULT` and nothing changes. Secondly, as described I am using `wx.BORDER_THEME` for all of my other widgets without this issue. So again, this tells me there is something going on with the grid widget and this has nothing to do with the border itself...

Comment: I stand corrected, there is a difference between the two borders. Why would using `wx.BORDER_THEME` not cause any issues at all for the 20 other widgets I am using? I still believe there is something odd going on between `wx.BORDER_THEME` and the grid widget.

Comment: You may very well be correct, in which case report it as a bug but I suspect that it is at the wxWidgets level, not wxPython. I'm happy to be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help out. I will report this as a bug and see where it goes, but I suspect you're right that it is probably something inherent in wxWidgets. Thanks Rolf :)

Comment: You can do something similar using a panel where you draw the border and then a sizer with the grid inside the panel.

Comment: @DanA.S., I did attempt this but it did not look right. I put `wx.TextCtrl`'s inside of a GridBagSizer. I also put in `wx.StaticLine`'s and spanned these horizontally and vertically to mimic the grid lines of a `wx.grid.Grid` but these lines did not look right. You could see where they are supposed to intersect they stopped just short, probably only a couple of pixels - but you could notice this. So I just scrapped this idea. If you think of a better solution let me know, thanks.